# Adding Editors to a Google Document with Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add editors and viewers to a Google Doc using Google Apps Script. The documentation of `addEditors()` says that:

> Adds the given array of users to the list of editors for the Document.

I can't figure out how to configure or use an array for this. The array is determined by values passed from a different script file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without any code to start with you need to do something like the following:

```
function addEditors() {
  var emails = [
    'john@example.com',
    'steve@example.com',
    'bill@example.com'
  ];

  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().addEditors(emails);
}
```

Arrays are a variable type in Javascript that you need to know to get started with Apps Script.

You can read more about arrays here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Or get some practice at FreeCodeCamp: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/store-multiple-values-in-one-variable-using-javascript-arrays

Good luck.