# Adding editors to a document by url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

As I saw in this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/43907485/2994412

I want to add/remove editors/viewers to many spreadsheets, but I have the URL, I'm not positioned in each document (sheets). The account running this script is the owner/creator of each file.

```
function addEditors() {
  var emails = [
    'john@example.com',
    'steve@example.com',
    'bill@example.com'
  ];

  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().addEditors(emails);
}
```

I couldn't find anything like `DocumentApp.getDocumtByURL('URL').addEditors(emails);`

I have all the URLs in a spreadsheet, I guess I could parse/get the ID, but how do I add/remove editors/viewers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You have several URLs of Google Spreadsheet, you want to add the editors and viewers using Google Apps Script.

  - And also, you want to remove them.
- The URL of Spreadsheet is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, it seems that Google Document is used. So in this case, Spreadsheet service is required to be used.
- When you have several URLs for Spreadsheet, you can use each URL in a loop.

#### Modified script 1:

In this script, `emails` are added as the editor for the Spreadsheets of URLs.

```
function addEditors() {
  var urls = [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit",
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];
  var emails = ["###","###",,,];

  urls.forEach(url => {
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).addEditors(emails);
  });
}
```

- When you want to add the emails as the viewers, please modify `addEditors(emails)` to `addViewers(emails)`.

#### Modified script 2:

In this script, the editors of `emails` are removed for the Spreadsheets of URLs.

```
function removeEditors() {
  var urls = [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit",
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];
  var emails = ["###","###",,,];

  urls.forEach(url => {
    emails.forEach(email => SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).removeEditor(email));
  });
}
```

- When you want to remove the viewers with the emails, please modify `removeEditor(email)` to `removeViewer(email)`.

#### References:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String))
- [addEditors(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addEditors(String))
- [addViewers(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addviewersemailaddresses)
- [removeEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeeditoremailaddress)
- [removeViewer(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removevieweremailaddress)